# How to style multiple tables differently, in html 5 with css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am currently working on a website for my business, from scratch using html5, css and javascript.

I have several table's I want to be styled individually e.g diff colours sizes etc.

I have tried to give them each their own class and I have done the table.table1 for my css - for all 3 but only one of the css is working, for all 3 tables it seems... where am I going wrong?

```html
<form name="htmlform" method="post" target="taxshop@hotmail" action="html_form_send.php">
  <table class="contact" width="450px">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6">                       
        </textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

The CSS I have for this table is as follows:

```css
table.contact tr, td {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color:#000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  padding: 4px;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 0.25em;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
table.contact, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
table.contact label{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  margin-right:10px;
  text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: your html is not good.. </tr> in top while no tr is starting..and please tell us the issue in detail. thank you

Comment: `<table>` is not specific to `HTML5`, it is in use from very early days of `HTML`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yvvcspha/ i fixed some of the obvious mistakes in this fiddle. And i really do not understant what are you trying to achive. You say that you have tried to style 3 tables, but i only see one, maybe you were talking about the rows?

Comment: Hi, yes i only included one table to show how i am ref' each 1 - the other two are .table1 & .table2 and similar css so i thought it would be too much info to include all 3. I need to know why it isnt working wen i have 3 diff css styles for 3 diff class tables. Basically i want the contact table centred and the other two i want to the left , diff b colours etc. thanks leon for pointing out my html is crap i have been trying to teach myself. i didnt go to university, all i have is 5 gcse grades a-c, 10 years work experience. I'm dyslexic so bear with me ! i will work it out myself eventually!

Comment: And besides, you really should not use tables to style forms in modern html.
Something like this, would work much better http://jsfiddle.net/26satzad/

Comment: Looks good IdeaMan thank you :-)

Comment: I am using whatever info i can get online - as well as some stuff from W3Schools - i have no idea where to find the more modern html tutorials :-)

Answer (score 1):

You had a mistake in a first row, 
https://jsfiddle.net/yvvcspha/1/

```
table.contact tr, td {
}
```

This selector means that youre applying style to ;`tr` inside `table.concat`, and to all other `td` on the page, since comma separates selectors.
If you want to apply style only to td inside `table.concat`, you should use. `table.contact td`.

```
table.contact tr, table.contact td {
}
```

This will be the right way to do it.

Also, consider learinig more about CSS and HTML5 basics since it seems like you're lacking some basic knowlege about their synthax and way it works.
**[This](http://learn.shayhowe.com/)**  series of articles (the beginer part) might end up being extrimely helpfull to you.

Comment: Ok so im trying the jsfiddle for this now - why is only one css filtering through to the html table display? js fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Hellsbells6787/z9w13wpf/   i also tried to edit your js fiddle to give each table different background colours and alignment etc and it seemed to only respond to one of the batches of css code. Any ideas?

Comment: Also forgot to mention - all the tables are on separate html web pages, i'm not sure if this even matters!

Comment: IdeaMan - can you please help me again? I am trying to do this - it still only seems to pick up the colour and use it for all three tables instead of just the one it has been specified in. See the fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/Hellsbells6787/yvvcspha/4/ - what i want is different coloured backgrounds for each table - i have tried different colours on my own table with the target selectors set the the class and it does the same thing.